# Removing decimals on yAxis in rCharts shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, rcharts, yaxis

I am plotting an nPlot using rCharts in shiny dashboard.. on the yAxis, i have big numbers (9 digits) plus 1 decimal (zero), please see this screenshot [yAxis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kB85.jpg)
I want to get rid of the zero (highlighted yellow), I have tried several solutions i found on stackoverflow, but nothing has worked till now

I tried to use format(round()) for the variable that is plotted in the yAxis

```
   ct$Market = as.character(ct$Market)
  output$top10markets <-renderChart({
    topmarkets <- 
      arrange(ct %>%  
                group_by(as.character(Market)) %>% 
                summarise(
                  CTo = format(round(sum(`Net turnover`)), digits = 0)
                ), desc(CTo))
    colnames(topmarkets)[colnames(topmarkets)=="as.character(Market)"] <- "Market"

    topmarkets <- subset(topmarkets[1:10,], select = c(Market, CTo))
    topmarkets$CTo <- format(round(topmarkets$CTo, digits = 0))

    p <- nPlot(CTo~Market, data = topmarkets, type = "discreteBarChart", dom = "top10markets") 
    p$params$width <- 1000
    p$params$height <- 200
    p$xAxis(staggerLabels = TRUE)
    p$yAxis(staggerLabels = TRUE, width = 10)

return(p)
```

})

and got this Error:***non-numeric argument to mathematical function***

I tried to use the TickFormat inside rCharts

```
p$yAxis(staggerLabels = TRUE, width = 50, tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return '€' + d} !#")
```

and got his result [yAxis with tickFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vSpv.jpg)  all commas are removed and still it overlaps the yAxis line

i tried also to add some CSS:

```
.nv-discreteBarWithAxes .nvd3 > g > g > text,
.nv-axisMaxMin text {
  transform: translateX(13px); 
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg); 
}
.nv-axisMaxMin text {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Result: in this screenshot [output with CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSHKf.jpg) 
also not good as numbers are exceeding the box borders!

I have tried also to change the box border sizes but it didn't help

Please any help?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the left margin with `p$chart(margin = list(left = 100))`, and you can set a padding in `p$yAxis` by doing `tickPadding = 15`.

The number formatter you want is `tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return d3.format('c')(8364) + d3.format(',.1')(d)} !#"` (8364 is the decimal code of the euro sign).

So:

```
library(rCharts)

dat <- data.frame(
  Market = c("A", "B", "C"),
  CTo = c(1000000, 5000000, 10000000)
)

p <- nPlot(CTo~Market, data = dat, type = "discreteBarChart")
p$yAxis(tickPadding = 15, tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return d3.format('c')(8364) + d3.format(',.1')(d)} !#")
p$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
p
```

[image]